# Javascript Promise doesn't resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous

I created a function that returns a promise which resolves to give me data sent over my API. It's called `getRequestData()`

```
async function getRequestData(req, res) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = [];
    req
      .on("data", (chunk) => {
        data.push(chunk);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        const dataDecoded = Buffer.concat(data).toString();
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(dataDecoded);
        resolve(parsedData);
      })
      .on("error", (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

I call this function in two places. The first one is where I create a new user. The `getRequestData()` function works well here.

```
async function createUser(req, res) {
  try {
    const userData = await getRequestData(req, res);
    const allRegisteredUsers = await getUsersFromDb();

    const users = parseUsersData(allRegisteredUsers)

    const userExists = users.find((user) => {
      return user.username === userData.username;
    });

    if (userExists) {
      return res.end("User already exists!");
    }

    users.push(userData);
    await writeUsersToDb(users);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
      message: "User created successfully",
      user: userData
    }))

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.statusCode = 400;
    return res.end("Error creating a new user!");
  }
}
```

In the second one, I call the getRequestData in a function that would create a new book in my DB, but the `getRequestData()` function never resolves here.

```
async function createBook(req, res) {
  try {
    const newBook = await getRequestData(req, res);
    console.log(newBook);
    res.end("Create new book");
  } catch (error) {
    res.writeHead(500)
    res.end(error);
  }
}
```

Any attempt to call the createBook function on my API tester (Thunder Client on VSCode) would result in the API not responding. I added `console.log` statements around my code and discovered that my `getRequestData()` function doesn't respond in the `createBook()` function.
[image: Thunder Client not responding]

Please, who knows what's going on?

For more context, this is the request handler

```
async function serverListener(req, res) {
  try {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    if (req.url === "/user/create" && req.method === "POST") {
      await createUser(req, res);
    } else if (req.url === "/users") {
      await authenticateUser(req, res, ["admin"])
      getAllUsers(req, res);
    } else if (req.url === "/book" && req.method === "POST") {
      await authenticateUser(req, res, ["admin"])
      createBook(req, res);
    } else if (req.url === "/book" && req.method === "PATCH") {
      await authenticateUser(req, res, ["admin"])
      updateBook(req, res);
    } else if (req.url === "/book" && req.method === "DELETE") {
      await authenticateUser(req, res, ["admin"])
      deleteBook(req, res);
    } else if (req.url === "/book/loan" && req.method === "POST") {
      loanOutBook(req, res);
    } else if (req.url === "/book/return" && req.method === "POST") {
      returnLoanedBook(req, res);
    } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end("The route does not exists.")
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.statusCode = 500;
    res.end(err);
  };
}
```

The `authenticateUser` function

```
function authenticateUser(req, res, roles) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const receivedData = await getRequestData(req, res);

      const userLoginData = receivedData.userLogin;

      if (!userLoginData) {
        return reject("You need to be authenticated to continue");
      }

      const allRegisteredUsers = await getUsersFromDb();

      const users = parseUsersData(allRegisteredUsers);

      const userFound = users.find((user) => {
        return (
          user.username === userLoginData.username &&
          user.password === userLoginData.password
        );
      });

      if (userFound && roles.includes(userFound.role)) {
        resolve(userFound);
      } else if (userFound && !roles.includes(userFound.role)) {
        res.statusCode = 401;
        reject(
          "You don't have the required permission to perform this operation."
        );
      } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        reject("Your user account doesn't exist! Create a new user.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Your `function getRequestData` has the `async` modifier - which means you shouldn't return a raw `Promise` from it. Remove the `async` modifier and see what happens.

Comment: okay, let me try that

Comment: I don't think that'll help, but it's good advice because there's no point in the `async` keyword if you never use `await` in the func. Are you calling this func twice on the same request? That probably won't work since the body has already been consumed. Please share a [mcve] showing the full call chain.

Comment: Still the same thing @Dai. Nothing changed

Comment: Yeah, the async was a mistake. I was using await in the function before.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm only calling the func once

Comment: So it's a separate request handler that calls `createBook`? What's the call chain leading to `createBook`? I assume there are no errors in the server during the hanging request? Where does the code block? If you're using Express, is there a reason you're not using body-parser? Sorry for all the questions, but such it is without a [mcve].

Comment: I would investigate the API, the problem doesn't seem to be in this code.

Comment: @ggorlen I just added the request handler to the question for more context.

Comment: @Barmar I think the API works just fine. I've checked it

Comment: Aha, for `createBook`, you call `authenticateUser` but for `createUser`, you don't!  So, can anyone create a user without authentication?  But anyway, I think `authenticateUser` is probably consuming the body of the request.

Comment: If you post the code for `authenticateUser`, we can confirm.

Comment: I'll post `authenticateUser` code in a bit and creating user without authenticating was intentional

Comment: Trying adding `await` before calling `createBook` in your `serverListener `

Comment: @SabbirAhmedSiddiquee nothing happens when I do that.

Comment: @user2740650 I've posted the code for `authenticateUser`.

Comment: Then try comment outing `authenticateUser ` call before calling `createBook`.
If it works now, you'll be sure that the issue is in `authenticateUser` function.

Comment: Yep, there's your problem. `authenticateUser` calls `getRequestData`, which consumes all the data from the request.  You can't call it twice in the same request because it will wait forever for more data which won't arrive.

Comment: Ohh! Let me try changing that

Comment: Really @ggorlen nailed it an hour ago when they said "Are you calling this func twice on the same request? "

Comment: Yeah, he said so. Kudos @ggorlen. I didn't get that at first because my approach was to get the data once at the top of the request handler before, but I can't remember when I changed that.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, `getRequestData` consumes the request body stream, so it'll hang forever if it's called a second time on the same request. You should probably call it one time as [*middleware*](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) (a high-level Express concept, discussed further below) on all routes that accept JSON payloads.

Beyond that, there are a good deal of apparent antipatterns in the code. If you're using Express, which it seems like you are based on the tag, all of the code you've presented is low-level request handling and routing that's already been written, tested and provided for your convenience by Express. In fact, that's the whole point of Express--to provide [`body-parser`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware and easy calls like `app.get()` and `app.post()` to parse JSON payloads and register [routes](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), among many other common tasks. It will automatically set `Content-Type` headers for you. With Express, you can replace almost all of the code here with a handful of lines that will be much easier to understand and maintain. Generally speaking, it's best to use the high-level tools provided to save time, keep code clean and avoid bugs, unless you're reinventing the wheel for educational purposes.

Also, I notice you have many asynchronous functions which aren't `await`ed, like `createBook(req, res);`. This takes the function out of the async `try`/`catch` error flow and (probably) returns an instantaneous success response for an operation that may well fail. This seems like an oversight and should be scrutinized thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks, @ggorlen. The code is meant to be in pure NodeJs that's why I'm doing stuff in low-level.

Comment: And I didn't get the last paragraph of your answer on having asynchronous functions which aren't `await`ed.

Comment: I'm not sure how to elaborate on it. If a function returns a promise (which is what happens when you label it `async`) and you fail to `await` it, you're introducing a race condition and taking that promise chain out of the error handling control flow. Don't you want `await loanOutBook(req, res);` rather than `loanOutBook(req, res);`? Otherwise, `} catch(err) {` in `serverListener` will only catch the couple of funcs you're `await`ing rather than all of the code it's wrapped around, as seems to be your intent, and all callers of `serverListener` won't wait for these operations to complete.

Comment: Sometimes it's intended to not `await` an `async` func but that's not the common case.

Comment: Oh! I understand now. I do intend to catch errors from all the functions in there.
Thanks, @ggorlen. I'll `await` the function now.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the rest of the application context, but, try this on the function `getRequestData`:

```js
async function getRequestData(req, res) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for await (const data of req ) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  });
}
```

Then, it would be nice if you send the application repository or something for us to try to run

Comment: What makes you think `req` is an array?

Comment: You're never sending the request to the API.

Comment: @Guilherme Teixeira Ais This is the repo. https://github.com/techemmy/Node-Bookstore-API

Comment: `req` isn't an array, but is a ReadleStream, so the data inside it can be retrieved with `for await`. But I'm not sure if this actually solves the problem.

Comment: @GuilhermeTeixeiraAis the `getRequestData` function works for other functions calling it. I don't think the error is from reading the stream.

Comment: @Emmanuel Oloyede
it really isn't... I'm looking at the code here to see if I can find something

Comment: @GuilhermeTeixeiraAis thanks for trying to help. I've resolved in the comments below the original post

Comment: Niiiice! It's the first time I try to help someone here on stackoverflow, I think I should've gone to the comments tab above there before creating an answer 

Comment: Yeah, You'll get used to it. Stack Overflow also indicates that you're a new contributor .